# Maximum call Stack size error on circular reference object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, circular-reference

I've an Object which contains circular references in it (references to DOM nodes). I've to save this object in local or session storage. To do this I was trying to do `JSON.stringify` and because of circular references I'm unable to stringify it.

This is how I'm getting the object that I've to save.

```
var elements = $("#content").children().detach();
```

After doing some research online most of the people suggested using cycle.js.

So I've tried using the [cycle.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) on elements variable, which will decycle the circular reference object. 
I've also tried [circular-json.js](https://github.com/WebReflection/circular-json), stringify-object.js

All these are throwing an Maximum call stack size exceeded error. I don't understand why I'm getting this error and how I could fix it.

Is there a way to get around this and save the object?

Comment: DomNodes are complex objects, with many methods and properties that will not be JSON valid. Perhaps you would like to get the DOM Html? This would return a string that you could immediately save. Otherwise I would advise that you determine what "Object" you are actually trying to store (what information from the dom element are you looking to reuse later) and pull that off into a simple object for the storage.

Comment: Why are you converting a dom html collection of nodes to JSON??? Makes no sense.

Comment: I've a datatable inside a ajax loaded div called content. I've to restore the datatable as it is, after switching one page to another. If I'm doing .html() to save the dom and put it back as string the javascript events on the datatable(click) are not working. Also it is making duplicate search boxes. Detach and append are working fine, but I'm not able to save them.

Comment: Well JSON is not the solution in the first place,,,that would make a string and would not copy events. Local Storage is also a string so that is not going to hold info either. You are going to have to rethink your design.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks for the help. Is there any other way to restore the dom which has events attached with it?

Comment: To save accross full page loads? no...once the document is destroyed it is bye bye.